# Refresh a DIV without refreshing the whole page, using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page named as table.php where i have 4divs. One div is for displaying an html table that fetches data from mysql database. I want to keep a button which will refresh and reload the table only with fresh data from the database. 
My codes: 
html:

```
<input type= "button" value= "Refresh" id="refresh" \>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        $("#table2").load("table.php")
    })
})
</script>
```

But the div is not refreshing the data. I have tried and checked but it is not updating new values on this button click. Please help.

Comment: Can you open up the console in Chrome or Firefox to see if there is any errors?

Comment: Could you please check if there are any errors? Maybe it's the browsers security preventing from loading anything.

Comment: This is the error:

TypeError: a.id.indexOf is not a function
http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/js/itn.js
Line 27

Comment: what is that script for?

Comment: what the console say?!

Comment: the firebug console is showing error stated in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get("table.php",function(data){$("#table2").html(data);});
```

or if you still wan't to use .load()

see the jquery api page for [global-ajax-event-handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
  console.log(exception);
});
```

Comment: still showing an error:

TypeError: a.id.indexOf is not a function
http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/js/itn.js
Line 27

Answer (score 0):

I think it is being refreshing but you are no getting any effect that it is being refreshed..

Try this actually

```
$("#refresh").click(function() {
    $("#table2").html("<h1>Loading...</h1>");
    $("#table2").load("table.php", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // May be alert
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough details about your program to give any concrete answers, but I have some general tips for debugging weird errors:

I think that the error message may have nothing to do with the code yo've shown. When a javascript error occurs, it often prevents the other scripts to run and terefore your code may not even run.

From the syntax in the code sample I assume this is jQuery or similar, and the script seems to be inline in the html. Try removing all other scripts that is not neded for your code to run.

It's a good general strategy when debugging javascript (especially when the error only appears in certain browsers that lack a good debugger), to comment out or remove script includes until the errors stop. This way you can at narrow down where the error might be triggered from.

Because of javascripts dynamic nature, errors may occur at seemingly random lines often with no trace back to the real cause. Also I'd suggest using [jslint](http://jslint.com/) (or similar) and testing the code often while writing code to catch small errors early and thus easier to find the line that caused it.